# SQL -Grab unique column combination from table

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I have a table called "MyTable".  This table has columns 'A' and 'B'.  I want to find every unique combination of 'A' and 'B'.  How would I do this?  I'd prefer to do this in SQL rather than PL/SQL.

Example:

### Column A | Column B

```
Dog           Cat
Cat           Dog
Horse         Cat
Dog           Cat
```

A unique combination above should return 3 rows.

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct columnA, columnB from table
```

or

```
select columnA, columnB from table
group by columnA, columnB
```

Comment: I work in SQL all the time, but just had brain fart this morning.  Thanks :)

Comment: What if I want columnC and columnD as well, but, those don't have to be distinct?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Select A, B
From MyTable
Group by A, B
```